# Google and .Net windows console progeam

Tags: google-drive-api

I need to write a windows console program that will take the results from a SQL query, and dump the results into a excel sheet.  We are moving away from Microsoft, and towards Google technology. So I need to create a worksheet, dump the results in that file, and store on drive.

Is the sdk the best way to go on this?  Am I going to need the SDK for Drive and for Worksheetes?  I also need to have the console run on it's own, no user interaction at all.  I have been working with this sample below, and got it to work. I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction with this. Any advice would be great!

```
using System;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Google;
    using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
    using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
    using Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;
    using Google.Apis.Services;
    using Google.Apis.Discovery;
    using Google.GData.Client;
    using Google.GData.Extensions;

     namespace GoogleDriveSamples
{
    class DriveCommandLineSample
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxx-bn0vi796pn7tog7utb9pt6pmptl8cpsq.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                    ClientSecret = "FwuyHxBAj2Z1",


                },
                new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None).Result;

            // Create the service.
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Credit Q",
            });



            File body = new File();
            body.Title = "My document";
            body.Description = "A test document";
            body.MimeType = "text/plain";

            byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("FTP.txt");
            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

            FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");
            request.Upload();

            File file = request.ResponseBody;
            Console.WriteLine("File id: " + file.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end this process.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in google apps script in about 5 lines of code.
Lok at the official samples. Basically use spreadsheetApp and jdbc.

Comment: Hi Zig! Thanks for the response.  I thought about apps, but we run all of our CMD, JAVA, PS1, ext scripts through one scheduling program.  I have a app, I wouldn't be able to have our scheduling program run it. Thanks  Jim

Comment: Apps script have their own scheduling built-in and run server-side on google servers. See time-based Triggers

Comment: Very interesting.  I'll have to check it out.  Thanks for the infoQ

Comment: The only issue with this, is that our firewall prevents Google apps to reach our SQL servers.  So I woouldn't be able to get to that data.  Thoughts?

Comment: If you must have the SQL with a firewall, your only option is to run it from your own servers, using the Drive api and spreadsheets api. You might be able to avoid using the spreadsheets api by generating an .xlsx file and uploading it with the drive api, with the "convert to native" set to true. In your sample code you did it with a .txt which wont convert. Also read about oauth2 for the proper way to authenticate to drive.

Comment: Hi Zig, Is a APP considered a web service?  I have the option of running web services from out scheduler. I did read about oauth2.  I'm having a mental block with that, just can't seem to get it to work in console window.  Another quick question, to create a brand new google worksheet I need the DRIV API, but to insert data into that worksheet I need the Worksheet API. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes a published script can be considered a webservice. Use drive api to create, spresdsheets api to manipulate its data. With apps script you dont need to know oauth

Comment: If so, please remove .net from title so this anwers applies.

Comment: Thanks for the great info Zig. So Just to be clear, If I use a app, I can create and modify worksheets in one little package?

Comment: It would be nice to convert some process to Google Apps, and run of the cloud. Maybe all of them. 95% of our processes touch our SQL DB's.  But I thought if I can dump the data into a xml from SQL, then dump the xml into the worksheet.   Thanks again for the great info!  Jim

Comment: See the Google Apps script docs and tutorials. You can do most all from an apps script, just beware of quotas.